# Is there a Node JS function or npm package that can find the Color depth of a screen?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to collect the color depth of anyone who runs my programs screen and was wondering if it was possible to do in nodejs. I know you can do it in vanilla JS with screen.Colordepth but I can't call that in Node. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: research on ncurses library for node.js

Comment: Are you trying to find the color depth of the screen of the computer that nodejs is running on or the color depth of some client that is contacting your server via an http request?

Comment: the color depth of the computer that nodejs is running on @jfriend00